# MYSQL query and LIMIT to one row

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

very simple but quite confusing to me:

```
SELECT `start`, `stop` FROM loadtime
WHERE utilisateur_id = '202931999'
AND `type` = 'stat'
AND `stop` !=0
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

12 sec

```
SELECT `start`, `stop` FROM loadtime
WHERE utilisateur_id = '202931999'
AND `type` = 'stat'
AND `stop` !=0
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,2 or xxx
```

0.07 sec

explain says 
limit 0, 1

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys             
1   SIMPLE     loadtime index   utilisateur_id_2,utilisateur_id,type    
key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
PRIMARY   4     NULL    10089   Using where
```

limit 0, x

```
id  select_type table     type      possible_keys
1   SIMPLE     loadtime   ref       utilisateur_id_2,utilisateur_id,type
key           key_len   ref     rows    Extra
utilisateur_id  62     const    12103   Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

so the first query doesn't use the index naturally.

[image: the indexes]

[image: the table]

server is on MySQL  5.5.32

Comment: Could you add the `EXPLAIN` output?

Comment: I guess you've executed first query, then second. After that second query used cache from first and was "fast"

Comment: I thought so as well but no matter how many times and in what order I run the query, the timings remain the same.

Comment: I am not sure but can u try to use "<>" this operator instead of "!=" and c if it changes something

Comment: I'm curious, I really dislike how the optimizer changes so much from one query to another similar one. +1

Comment: Can you tell us your MySQL server version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple: for some reason (which can be [many](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html)) MySQL server decides that in the `limit 0,1` case it is a better idea (i.e. the server expects that it would take less time and computation) to do a full table scan in order to give you the right result, instead of using an index.

Since this is a prediction, [it could happen that it may be wrong](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/7-ways-to-convince-mysql-to-use-the-right-index) and using an index would work better (as in the `limit 0,x` case). Since you noticed the performance difference, you can force the query to use the index you think is the best, as follows (and as suggested [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html)):

```
SELECT `start`, `stop` FORCE INDEX (condition) FROM loadtime
WHERE utilisateur_id = '202931999'
AND `type` = 'stat'
AND `stop` !=0
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: yes you're right, i actually forced the index FORCE INDEX (utilisateur_id) and the works of course as expected. From the analysis I made, the full table scan would come from the fact that WHERE utilisateur_id = '202931999' occurs around 20k times in the data. Still I don't get why this happens in the limit 0, 1 case